# Display Different Drop Down list values based on a textbox value of Integer Data type

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am struck at this point. Hope you understands my problem
I have a drop down list field called "Address type" where it has values like Home, Office, Other, Hostel. I have another text field called ID which is an integer type. I want to get the values of drop-down list based on the text field automatically from the DB.

```
Example: 
       ID 1 : Drop Down Values-Home, Other
       ID 2 : Drop Down Values-Home, Other, Hostel
       ID 3 : Drop Down Values-Office.
```

SQL Query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Address_Type FROM Contact_AddressInfo WHERE ContactID =XXX
```

ASP Code:

```
 protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();            
       con.Open();// Already declared the connection string
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Address_Type FROM Contact_AddressInfo WHERE ContactID ='" + TextBox.Text + "'",con);
       DropDownList.SelectedValue = cmd.ToString();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close(); 
       ddl.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
       ddl.DataValueField = "Address_Type"; 
       ddl.DataTextField = "Address_Type";
       ddl.DataBind();

 }
```

The Query is working fine in sql Server, but I am trying this to implement in asp.net. Any help is helpful

Comment: Show your asp code..

Comment: @PradnyaBolli U can see my asp code..

Comment: your code is fine, where is issue comes, if you pass textbox value, it definately bind dropdown(if your dataset return properly)

Comment: @PradnyaBolli Thanks for your code. But it seems it doesn't work for me. As the pick list values doesn't changes at all even though I selected the different id's.

Comment: @Ajay2707 My aim is to display different dropdown list values based on id. Now it is displaying all dropdown values irrespective of the id.

Comment: Set your dropdownlist `Autopostback` property true.

Comment: this means your id is not passed, just hardcord(textbox1.text value) it and check. This is very basic functionality, http://www.aspsnippets.com/Red/Articles/DataBinding-DropDownList-Label-and-Textbox-Controls-in-ASP.Net.aspx. you just google "bind dropdown value inline sql query asp.net"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you want to change your dropdown values changes when you change value in textbox. if yes, then genrate textbox's OnChange() event in your code behind and rebind your dropdown by passing the textbox value.

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Address_Type FROM 
Contact_AddressInfo WHERE ContactID ='" + TextBox.Text + "'", con);
SqlDataReader ddlValues;
ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();
ddl.DataSource = ddlValues;
ddl.DataValueField = "Address_Type";
ddl.DataTextField = "Address_Type";
ddl.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This..I hope this work for your project..

```
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SSELECT DISTINCT Address_Type FROM Contact_AddressInfo WHERE ContactID ='" + TextBox.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataReader ddlValues;
        ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        ddl.DataSource = ddlValues;
        ddl.DataValueField = "Address_Type";
        ddl.DataTextField = "Address_Type";
        ddl.DataBind();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--select Item Name--", "0"));
        con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
ddl.DataValueField = "Address_Type"; 
ddl.DataTextField = "Address_Type";
ddl.DataBind();
```

To get the equivalent address as selected in your drop down list.

```
ddl.SelectedValue = Int32.parse(TextBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove DropDownList.SelectedValue = cmd.ToString(); and use a DataAdapter to Fill your DataTable. As it is now your command is not returning any values to your code.

Comment: @feman Thanks for your post. I tried that before several times but doesn't work.

Comment: @bvphani413 where in your code are you filling your table dataset.Tables[0]? definetly not from within your code snippet...